# Snowpipe auto ingestion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to Snowflake. I have created snowpipe, stages also configured SQS in AWS.

Data is not getting loaded into table through snowpipe when I placed files in my S3 bucket.

If I'm executing statement: alter pipe snow_pipename refresh then only data getting loaded into table.

Do I need to do any more setup/instructions for auto ingest data load.

Comment: You can debug using the steps listed here:https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#option-2-configuring-amazon-sns-to-automate-snowpipe-using-sqs-notifications

Answer (score 0):

The SQS notification might not have been set up properly on the S3 bucket. Check the configuration to set it up in the below link

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#step-4-configure-event-notifications

Comment: I have Performed below steps: create or replace stage snowpipe_emp url='s3://YYYYYY';
  list @snowpipe_emp;
  create table snowpipe_emp_table(
  Name String,
  Dept string,
  Sal number);  
create pipe snowpipe_pipe_emp 
auto_ingest=true
as copy into snowpipe_emp_table from @snowpipe_emp
file_format=csvfile;
show pipes; In AWS events, selected option All object create events, Send to: SQS Queue , SQS: Add SQS queue ARN, SQS queue ARN:updated notificationchannel whic I got from pipes. Still data loading is not working.

Comment: Snowpipe remembers file names while loading to avoid duplicates. Can you try with a new file? If it doesn't work, please open a support ticket with details.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have configured your snowflake IAM role correctly with appropriate policies and trust relationship.

Step 5 of the documentation:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#step-4-configure-event-notifications

Also, ensure that these values are reflected in your `STAGE_CREDENTIALS` within your stage, using `DESCRIBE STAGE snowpipe_emp;`